# Trouble regarding user registration form in Django

Tags: python, html, django

Okay, so I have this HTML form:

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="register">Login</button>
</form>
```

And this Django view:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_user = form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/success/")
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
        return render_to_response("signup.html", {'form': form,}, RequestContext(request))
```

This works perfectly fine. But I want to be able to customize the original form a bit more. So, in order to try and figure out how to do that, I first look at the source code for the form.as_p function and try and replicate it manually. I end up with this:

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
        <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="id_password1">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password1" id="id_password">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="id_password2">Password confirmation:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password2" id="id_password2">
    </p>

    <button type="submit" value="register">Login</button>
</form>
```

However, this doesn't work. I can't understand why it doesn't. If form.as_p has the above as the output then it theoretically should work fine with the view shouldn't it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In theory it should work fine. What isn't working exactly? Do you manage to view the html? Does your server register a request when you press the submit button?

Comment: It sends a successful POST request, but it returns to the same page, as it should if the form has not been submitted properly (form.is_valid is false).

Comment: for first password field, is it `password` or `password1`. If the id is `id_password` then you have a typo there, for `for="id_password1"` should be `for="id_password"` and name should be `name="password"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template misses out two things: any form or field errors, and any pre-populated values of the fields. What's clearly happening is that is_valid is indeed false, but you're not showing any of the errors.

Instead of hard-coding the fields in HTML, you should use the template variables:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
...
<p>
{{ form.username.label_tag }}
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.username.errors }}
</p>
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks! What would be the best implementation for password and password confirmation?